# Ruby on Rails in a git hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, hook

I am in the process of building a Rails app that will hook into a git repository and will execute some code whenever the repository is pushed to. I am trying to do this using git hooks, but I can't seem to be able to work with the Rails app from within said hooks.

I have tried using rails runner as the shebang (#!/path/to/rails runner) of the hooks but because the space is not considered an argument separator in shebangs this tries to execute a file called "rails runner" which does not work. I have also tried executing the script as Ruby (#!/usr/bin/ruby) and including the rails config/environment.rb file, but this seems to trigger the old "app/models/X.rb Expected to define X" error. I don't have the code on me at the moment so I can't paste the intended functionality to see if there's just an error in my code somewhere, but I just want to know what the correct approach to executing Rails code outside of the Rails app path is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `/usr/bin/env` trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /path/to/rails runner
```

The [`env` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) just runs its arguments as a normal command, it is usually used to perform `PATH` searches for things in the shebang.

Comment: I have just tried this by setting up a small .sh script and running it with ./ - I got the following result:
/usr/bin/env: /usr/bin/rails runner: No such file or directory
This seems to tie in with the problem i mentioned before about arguments not being split in shebangs?

Comment: That said, I don't think you you use rails runner like this.  It expects the input to be a command line argument, rather the stdin.

Comment: @mrnoob1: A file with only `#!/usr/bin/env ls /` and a 0755 mode gives me an `ls` of `/` when I executed it. You should be able to supply arguments in a shebang line. What OS are you using?

Comment: @d11wtq: You can feed a whole script to `rails runner` just like any other interpreter. For example, `#!/usr/bin/env ruby /path/to/rails runner\nputs 'hi'` (where `\n` is a real newline) works fine for me with 3.1.

Comment: trying your example, i got the following message:
/usr/bin/env: ls /: No such file or directory
I am currently using a Debian server which annoyingly seems to behave differently from the ubuntu laptop i am using for development - I will test all these out once i get access to my laptop again as im sure the answer lies in your suggestion

Comment: Ah, right, I just tried on 3.0.7 doing `echo 'puts "hello"' | rails runner` and all I got was the help dialog telling me how to use the runner :)

Comment: @mrnoob1: How old is your Debian server? I just tried it with an old Debian box and I got the same bizarre results that you did. OTOH, a simple `#!/bin/ls /` one liner behaves itself. @d11wtq's approach might be the best way to get consistent results. I love standards, there are so many to choose from.

Comment: Yeah, fully undocumented and unstandardized shebangs + fully undocumented and unstandardized rails hooking = recipe for problems. Cheers for the suggestions.

Comment: @mrnoob1, @d11wtq: I'd probably set it all up as a rake task and then execute that task from a simple shell script. That should work the same everywhere and would be (IMHO) cleaner and more standard than using runner. But, as usual, whatever works works.

Answer (score 2):

If what @mu is too short has suggested doesn't work, you might try just triggering a method inside your Rails app, keeping most of the code inside the app, and not in the git hook.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

bundle exec rails runner 'SomeJob.perform'
```

Where the `#perform` method of `SomeJob` does the actual work and your shell script is merely invoking it.